# Why is it said that dimensional models (DM/DW) are denormalized when most of them are in 1NF?

Tags: database, normalization, data-modeling, data-warehouse, database-normalization

Currently I am working with the Dimensional modeling / Data Warehouse / Data Mart.

"Dimensional modeling" is the data model of the data warehouse. There are two basic models: "star schema" and "snowflake schema"

Dimensional modelling is used for OLAP (Online Analytical Processing).

I have been reading about dimensional modeling and OLAP, and this kind of database is described as "denormalized."

But since I work with them, I see all the data structures always minimally in 1NF. I have never worked with a completely denormalized database structure.

So here is the question, does 1NF mean the same thing as "denormalized?" If not, then why do people say it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is denormalised in comparison to more commonly used relational models, which are very often 3NF+. The assumption is that your source systems are using 3NF+ databases, and when you drop down to 2NF or 1NF, you are denormalising.

This is a big assumption, and not always correct. Plenty of systems are built on relational databases which don't really follow a 3NF model. And more recently, some systems are not using a relational model at all! (Think about all the NoSQL data stores now in use.)

Further to this, one fairly common data warehouse architecture involves creating a 3NF+ datawarehouse which is loaded from the source, and then denormalising the data to create dimensional data marts which are loaded from the more normalised model. In this case saying you are "denormalising" makes sense.